# Insert string in beginning of another string

Tags: java, string

How to insert a string enclosed with double quotes in the beginning of the StringBuilder and String?

Eg:

```
StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder("Sam");
```

I need to insert the string "Hello" to the beginning of "Sam" and O/p is "Hello Sam".

```
String _s = "Jam";
```

I need to insert the string "Hello" to the beginning of "Jam" and O/p is "Hello Jam".

How to achieve this?

Comment: Don't you mean, insert the string Jam to the end of Hello?

Comment: No, Hello to the beginning of Jam as _s be initialized with Jam

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The first case is done using the `insert()` method:

```
_sb.insert(0, "Hello ");
```

The latter case can be done using the overloaded + operator on Strings. This uses a StringBuilder behind the scenes:

```
String s2 = "Hello " + _s;
```

Comment: How do you know that this uses a StringBuilder behind the scenes ?

Comment: @MasterJoe: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048633/java-compiler-replacing-stringbuilder-with-concatenation) question!

Answer (score 17):

Other answers explain how to insert a string at the beginning of another `String` or `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`).

However, strictly speaking, you cannot insert a string **into** the beginning of another one.  Strings in Java are immutable<sup>1</sup>.

When you write:

```
String s = "Jam";
s = "Hello " + s;
```

you are actually causing a new `String` object to be created that is the concatenation of "Hello " and "Jam".  You are not actually inserting characters into an existing `String` object at all.

---

<sup>1 - It is technically possible to use reflection to break abstraction on `String` objects and mutate them ... even though they are immutable *by design*.  But it is a *really bad idea* to do this.  Unless you know that a `String` object was created explicitly via `new String(...)` it could be shared, or it could share internal state with other `String` objects.  Finally, the JVM spec clearly states that the behavior of code that uses reflection to change a `final` is undefined.  Mutation of `String` objects is dangerous.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Sure, use [`StringBuilder.insert()`](http://bit.ly/3VN1C2):

```
_sb.insert(0, _s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a string at the front of an already existing one. for example, if I have a name string `name`, I can add another string `name2` by using:

```
name = name2 + name;
```

Don't know if this is helpful or not, but it works. No need to use a string builder.

Comment: OP asks about StringBuilder and a String -- that's what answers are supposed to address. Given that there are already quite good answers to this question, with the most upvoted also being the accepted one, it's advisable that new answers bring something in addition.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static void appendZeroAtStart() {
        String strObj = "11";
        int maxLegth = 5;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strObj);
        if (sb.length() <= maxLegth) {
            while (sb.length() < maxLegth) {
                sb.insert(0, '0');
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }

        System.out.println("result: " + sb);

    }
```

Answer (score -7):

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create a new StringBuilder.
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop and append values.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        builder.append("abc ");
    }
    // Convert to string.
    String result = builder.toString();

    // Print result.
    System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the original post, it uses Strings and StringBuilder, but it does not "insert a string enclosed with double quotes in the beginning of the StringBuilding".

Answer (score -13):

It is better if you find quotation marks by using the `indexof()` method and then add a string behind that index.

```
string s="hai";
int s=s.indexof(""");
```

Comment: The string does not contain `"`