# Java Compiler replacing StringBuilder with + concatenation

Tags: java, stringbuilder, compiler-optimization

Here's some simple Java code:

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").append("c").toString();
```

I compile it with JRE 1.6, and I observe the following in the decompiled class file:

```
String s = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

I had the following questions:

1. Why does the compiler choose '+' over StringBuilder?
2. Do we have any official Java specification that justifies this behavior?
3. Does it really make sense to use StringBuilder in such cases, where we know compiler is going to change it anyway?

Comment: Are you sure you've decompiled the correct version of your class?

Comment: What you're seeing is the decompiler trying to be smart, not how the compiled code actually looks.

Comment: `StringBuilder` for constant strings does not make sense. If I write `String s = "a" + "b" + "c";` compiler produces line that using `javap -c` is shown like this: `0: ldc #2 // String abc`. So it is smart and constant strings are "glued" into one. This means we can use + for code formatting purposes "for free" which is quite important.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the other way round.  `+` for `String` is implemented using `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`) behind the scenes (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

Thus, once they're compiled, your two code snippets are indistinguishable.  The decompiler has to make a guess at the original form.

Answer (score 2):

1. The decompiler must have assumed that the bytecode instructions to call `append` over and over resulted from source code that used the `+` operator.
2. [Section 15.18.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) specifies that a compiler can use a `StringBuffer` or similar means to implement the `+` operator between `String`s:

   > An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.

   The `StringBuilder` class is a "similar technique".
3. In this case, you can use either technique to concatenate your strings.  If you have lots of complicated operations yielding strings that need to be concatenated, then you would be better off using a `StringBuilder` and appending them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about JDK 1.6 (javac is part of JDK) but when I compile it with JDK 1.7, I get an appropriate [disassembly](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/344addc9a1d1bd21dc45).

The compilers are smart. In JDK, I think if you have s = "a" + "b" + "c" it will perhaps do it this way (use StringBuilder instead), but not the other way. More concretely, if all strings are compile-time constants (string literals) it will do even better -- calculate the string literal and replace the concatenation with that, so there will be less overhead at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

*Just For Reference*

Your questions have already been answered by Oliver Charlesworth but I think you are checking the wrong place to start this question.

You should check the ByteCode using `javap -v YouClass.class` instead of using the IDE to check the **decompiled** code which can be quite confusing.

The original java code

```
public class LockElimination {
    private static String concat(String s1, String s2, String s3) {
        return s1 + s2 + s3;
    }
}
```

The ByteCode generated by `javap -v LockElimination.class`

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #7.#16         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #17            // java/lang/StringBuilder
   #3 = Methodref          #2.#16         // java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   #4 = Methodref          #2.#18         // java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   #5 = Methodref          #2.#19         // java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
```